# Gif loaded with Glide in RecyclerView Adapter not playing properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, android-viewholder

I have a recyclerview which shows a list of images in horizontal view. I want to show a gif around each imageview like an outline similar to instagram's story view.

Here is the code for loading the same.

```
GlideApp
        .with(itemView.context).asGif()
        .load(R.drawable.red)
        .error(R.drawable.red)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
        .into(ivBackground)
```

I tried adding this code on both places i.e. `onCreateViewHolder` as well as `onBindViewHolder` but the gif is not playing properly.

It only shows one frame at a time. If I pause current activity by pressing the back button and then from recent app menu, navigate back to the app, then it shows the next frame.

My gif is stored in the drawable folder and I have the exact same gif working properly in an activity/fragment.

Issue is it's not playing properly inside a recyclerview adapter.

This is the complete adapter class.

```
    class LiveViewAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    val liveList: ArrayList<DataItem>,
    private val listener: LiveViewAdapterListener
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<LiveViewHolder>() {
    private val inflater: LayoutInflater

    interface LiveViewAdapterListener {
        fun onLiveClicked(url: String)
    }

    init {

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LiveViewHolder {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_live, parent, false)

        return LiveViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return liveList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LiveViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val requestOptions = RequestOptions().apply {
            placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
        }
        val videoId = liveList[holder.adapterPosition].liveUrl?.substring(liveList[holder.adapterPosition].liveUrl?.lastIndexOf("=")!! + 1)
        val imageUrl = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/$videoId/hqdefault.jpg"
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(liveList[position].liveUrl)
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .thumbnail(Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl))
            .into(holder.ivLive)


        holder.ivLive.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onLiveClicked(liveList[holder.adapterPosition].liveUrl!!)
        }
    }
}
```

Glide version used

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

**UPDATE**

I figured out that the above code works fine on android devices which have sdk version less than pie. On devices with android pie, it's not working properly.

Comment: Which version of Glide are you using? I am using Glide to load gif in a recyclerview and I do not have a problem.

Comment: Seems like code of `GlideApp` is perfect. There is may be other problem in `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

Comment: @sanjeev added glide dependency

Comment: Well I just used this to load a gif, and works just fine. `Glide.with(getActivity()).load(myList.get(position).getBgimg()).into(holder.card_main);`

Comment: @sanjeev seems like you are loading from url. In my case I am using from drawable

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `roundedImageView` or just native `imageview` ?

I met the same the same problem while using `roundedImageView`. I replace it with native `ImageView`, the gif play.